# Appropriate timeouts for libcurl

Tags: curl, proxy, timeout, libcurl

Situation: uploading and downloading large files.

Every now and then I encounter a proxy that accepts the full request immediately (at full LAN speed), and then forwards it slowly over the internet.  Its normally some unknown corporate proxy, but today I can simulate it with the BurpSuite proxy.

It seems difficult to configure a timeout for CURL that will handle this situation.
At the moment, I'm using low-speed timeouts, since I don't know how long the full transfer will take (ie I can't use the usual CURLOPT_TIMEOUT).

The problem with this kind of proxy, the whole request is sent right at the start (average speed = 1.7e+07 B/s) and then after a dozen seconds or so, the average speed drops below the threshold... timeout!

The large download situation is different again.
A small GET request goes to the proxy, which then downloads the entire response first before passing it onto the client.  I see this sometimes in the field, there is a very long delay and then suddenly the download finishes very quickly.

Any idea how this kind of thing should be correctly handled?

Comment: You should probably consider writing your own custom timeout logic with `CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION` ...

Comment: Thanks @DanielStenberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I eventually used, and so I'm accepting

The problem (at first) was that a large upload would go very quickly, and then pause at the end while the proxy forwarded the data.  This would trigger the low-speed timeout before the proxy had finished the transfer and returned the response.

So the code below would disable the low-speed timeout when the upload was done, and then simply wait forever for the final response (not ideal).

BUT, this did not help with downloads through this strange proxy.

The proxy would download but not forward anything on until it had completed the download (except perhaps a byte per minute).  So the low-speed timeout would trip if the download was any larger than about 20MB.

So in the end I disabled all timeouts completely, and am not sure whether I can do anything better at all...

Here is the code, but note again that it didn't help with large downloads.
It would probably be ok if you turn the low-speed timeout right down to about 1 byte per minute or something similar.

```
int progress_callback(void * clientp, curl_off_t dltotal, curl_off_t dlnow, curl_off_t ultotal, curl_off_t ulnow)
{
   // a pseudo-member function, but its actually a static member for callback
   NetConfig * self = static_cast<NetConfig*>(clientp);

   // Now deal with the low-speed timeout.
   // some proxies accept the whole transfer at once and then forward,
   // giving the appearance of the connection "hung" at the end.
   // We cannot turn off the low-speed limit when we have a proxy configured,
   // because some sites have transparent proxies, so the plain network
   // behaves in this fashion.

   // IF we have finished the transfer, then disable the low speed timeout.

   // we only do this in the Timeout_Slow mode
   if (self->timeout_mode == Timeout_Slow)
   {
      bool want_lowspeed = (dltotal > 0 and dlnow < dltotal)
                        or (ultotal > 0 and ulnow < ultotal);

      if (want_lowspeed != self->lowspeed_limit_enabled)
      {
         if (want_lowspeed)
         {
            curl_easy_setopt(self->handle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, timeout_slow.first);
            curl_easy_setopt(self->handle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, timeout_slow.second);
         }
         else
         {
            curl_easy_setopt(self->handle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, (long)0L);
            curl_easy_setopt(self->handle, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, (long)0L);
         }
         self->lowspeed_limit_enabled = want_lowspeed;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to code custom read and write timeouts in addition to curl's builtin connection timeout.

This is easiest done with curl_multi (you can code a solution with curl_easy via `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`, but I find such things too fragile to my liking).

Here is a code of "blocking read", using the multi interface (`curl_data` is a custom structure with stuff):

```
static bool curlPerform(struct curl_data* ctrl) {
  int timeout = ctrl->timeout;

  struct timespec timeoutTimestamp, currentTimestamp;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timeoutTimestamp);

  int fdEvents = 0;

  do {
    if (*ctrl->interrupted) {
        return false;
    }

    int running;

    LOG("Invoking perform()");

    CURLMcode result = curl_multi_perform(ctrl->multi, &running);

    if (result) {
        handleMultiError(ctrl, result);
        return true;
    }

    if (checkResult(ctrl)) {
        LOG("Has completed connections, bailing");
        return true;
    }

    if (running == 0) {
        LOG("No running connections, bailing");
        return true;
    }

    if (*ctrl->interrupted) {
        return false;
    }

    long waitTime;
    curl_multi_timeout(ctrl->multi, &waitTime);

    if (timeout < waitTime) {
        waitTime = timeout;
    }

    LOG("Timeout is %d, waiting for %ld", timeout, waitTime);

    if (waitTime > 0) {
        CURLMcode waitResult = curl_multi_wait(ctrl->multi, NULL, 0, waitTime, &fdEvents);

        if (waitResult) {
            handleMultiError(ctrl, waitResult);
            return true;
        }
    }

    LOG("Sockets with events: %d", fdEvents);

    if (fdEvents) {
        timeout = ctrl->timeout;
    } else {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &currentTimestamp);

        timeout -= ((currentTimestamp.tv_sec - timeoutTimestamp.tv_sec) * 1000);

        int diff_nsec = currentTimestamp.tv_nsec - timeoutTimestamp.tv_nsec;

        if (diff_nsec < 0) {
            timeout += 1000;
            timeout -= ((diff_nsec + 1000000000) / 1000000);
        }

        if (timeout <= 0) {
            LOG("Remaining time is %d, bailing", timeout);
            throwTimeout(ctrl->env, ctrl->headerPairCount);
            return true;
        }

        timeoutTimestamp = currentTimestamp;
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

The code above is a stripped down version of [this code](https://github.com/Alexander--/chttpc/blob/master/lib/src/main/jni/native-lib.c) with most irrelevant stuff removed. It essentially implements curl_easy on top of curl_multi with added ability to exit upon errors, connection and read timeouts.

In order to adapt that code to your needs, you will have to implement two small changes:

1. Separate read timeout from write timeout;
2. Start enforcing read timeout only after first bytes of data (not headers!) arrive.

You can track request/response progress by supplying `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`/`CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`. Once the read function has uploaded all data, stop enforcing write timeout (for example by setting ctrl->timeout to `INT_MAX`). Once the write function registers arrival of the first content byte, start enforcing read timeout.

Comment: Ideally my code should not end up as a big copy-paste-and-hack chunk of code.  So far, I've followed Daniel's advice and added a little code into CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, which turns off the low-speed thresholds after all of the data has been uploaded.
Note also that I couldn't just turn it off every time there is a proxy defined, because one of the networks has a transparent proxy.